# How to chain .dll dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

Lets say I have three projects and the following artifacts:

`Program.exe`:

```
namespace Program {
    class Foo {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            ClassLibrary1.CL1Foo.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

`ClassLibrary1.dll`:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1 {
    class CL1Foo {
        static void doSomething() {
            ClassLibrary2.CL2Foo.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

`ClassLibrary2.dll`:

```
namespace ClassLibrary2 {
    class CL1Foo {
        static void doSomething() { }
    }
}
```

`Program.exe` has `ClassLibrary1` as a reference, `ClassLibrary1` has `ClassLibrary2` as a reference. The `ClassLibrary1` reference won't work, though, without all its dependencies (i.e. `ClassLibrary2.dll`) being copied over along with it.

How can you make sure that all `ClassLibrary1`'s dependencies are copied over to `Program.exe`'s build output folder, even when`ClassLibrary1`'s dependencies might change?

Comment: Doesn't visual studio take care of that? Do you have any problems?

Comment: @nvoigt it only will output `ClassLibrary1.dll` to `Program`'s build output. It doesn't output `ClassLibrary2`. This is VS 2010

Comment: Presumably you find out the problem pretty quickly, don't you? If you use NuGet for package management, it will take care of all of this, mind you.

Comment: Visual studio normally does just that, if it isnt try checking the properties of your reference and see if nothing has been changed like copy local, or try re-adding the references